# java.io.IOException: Stream closed with WS call

Tags: java, ios, web-services

I am facing an issue, when I try to connect to the WS some time I am getting java.io.IOException: Stream closed. This is not reproducible systematically.  If I run the same thing again it works well.
Can any body please help me ?

Code which calls this WS is

```
public Long startProcess(String pId, Map<String,Object> params) throws OmegaFunctionalException{//Start JBPM Process with parameter Map
             LOG.debug("inside startProcess...");

             LOG.debug("applicationConfiguration.getJbpmWsUrl() = {}", applicationConfiguration.getJbpmWsUrl().toString());
             WorkflowHandlerServiceService webProvider = new WorkflowHandlerServiceService(applicationConfiguration.getJbpmWsUrl());
             LOG.debug("webProvider.getPort...");
             WorkflowHandlerService webService = webProvider.getPort(WorkflowHandlerService.class);
             JbpmParameterItemArray itemArray = new JbpmParameterItemArray();
             try {
                    itemArray.setItem(JbpmParameterItem.buildList(params));
                    LOG.debug("webService.startProcess...");
                    return webService.startProcess(pId, itemArray);
             } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException ex) {
                    LOG.debug("ClassNotFoundException or IOException");
                    LOG.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
                    throw new OmegaTechnicalException(ex);
             } catch (OmegaWSException ex) {
                    LOG.debug("OmegaWSException");
                    Exception generatedException = ex.getFaultInfo().generateException();
                    if (generatedException instanceof OmegaFunctionalException){
                           LOG.debug("OmegaFunctionalException");
                           LOG.error(generatedException.getMessage(), generatedException);
                           throw (OmegaFunctionalException) generatedException;
                    } 

                    LOG.error(generatedException.getMessage(), generatedException);
                    throw new OmegaTechnicalException(ex.getMessage(),generatedException);
             } catch (Exception ex) {
                    LOG.debug("Exception......");                  
                    if (ex instanceof SOAPFaultException)
                    {
                           SOAPFaultException e = (SOAPFaultException) ex;
                           LOG.debug("ex.getFault().getFaultCode() : {}", e.getFault().getFaultCode());
                           LOG.debug("ex.getFault().getFaultCodeAsName() : {}", e.getFault().getFaultCodeAsName().toString());
                           LOG.debug("ex.getFault().getFaultCodeAsQName() : {}", e.getFault().getFaultCodeAsQName().toString());
                           LOG.debug("ex.getFault().getFaultString() : {}", e.getFault().getFaultString());
                           //LOG.debug("ex.getFault().getDetail() : {}", e.getFault().getDetail().toString());
                    }

                    LOG.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
                    throw new OmegaTechnicalException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
             }
       }
```

And other class

```
/**
* This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
* JAX-WS RI 2.2.8
* Generated source version: 2.2
* 
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "WorkflowHandlerServiceService", targetNamespace = "http://workflow.core.omega2.scor.com/", wsdlLocation = "http://localhost:8080/omega2-ws/services/shared?wsdl")
@HandlerChain(file="handlers.xml")
public class WorkflowHandlerServiceService
    extends Service
{

    private final static URL WORKFLOWHANDLERSERVICESERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static WebServiceException WORKFLOWHANDLERSERVICESERVICE_EXCEPTION;
    private final static QName WORKFLOWHANDLERSERVICESERVICE_QNAME = new QName("http://workflow.core.omega2.scor.com/", "WorkflowHandlerServiceService");

    static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/omega2-ws/services/shared?wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
        WORKFLOWHANDLERSERVICESERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
        WORKFLOWHANDLERSERVICESERVICE_EXCEPTION = e;
    }

    public WorkflowHandlerServiceService() {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), WORKFLOWHANDLERSERVICESERVICE_QNAME);
    }

    public WorkflowHandlerServiceService(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), WORKFLOWHANDLERSERVICESERVICE_QNAME, features);
    }

    public WorkflowHandlerServiceService(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, WORKFLOWHANDLERSERVICESERVICE_QNAME);
    }

    public WorkflowHandlerServiceService(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, WORKFLOWHANDLERSERVICESERVICE_QNAME, features);
    }

    public WorkflowHandlerServiceService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public WorkflowHandlerServiceService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     returns WorkflowHandlerService
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "WorkflowHandlerServicePort")
    public WorkflowHandlerService getWorkflowHandlerServicePort() {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://workflow.core.omega2.scor.com/", "WorkflowHandlerServicePort"), WorkflowHandlerService.class);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param features
     *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
     * @return
     *     returns WorkflowHandlerService
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "WorkflowHandlerServicePort")
    public WorkflowHandlerService getWorkflowHandlerServicePort(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://workflow.core.omega2.scor.com/", "WorkflowHandlerServicePort"), WorkflowHandlerService.class, features);
    }

    private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
        if (WORKFLOWHANDLERSERVICESERVICE_EXCEPTION!= null) {
            throw WORKFLOWHANDLERSERVICESERVICE_EXCEPTION;
        }

        /*ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration = CoreBeanApplicationContext.getBean("applicationConfiguration");
        if (applicationConfiguration.getJbpmWsUrl() != null){
                return applicationConfiguration.getJbpmWsUrl();
        }*/
        return WORKFLOWHANDLERSERVICESERVICE_WSDL_LOCATION;
    }

}
```

Below is the stack trace.

```
com.scor.omega2.batch.core.BatchException: 6 [RUNTIME_ERROR] Error while executing batch SINJ3010: java.io.IOException: Stream closed.
                at com.scor.omega2.batch.executor.RunnableBatchServiceExecutor.run(RunnableBatchServiceExecutor.java:151) ~[reins-batch-servlet-1.0-20151127.125731-11.jar:na]
                at com.scor.omega2.batch.executor.RunnableBatchServiceExecutor.runSynchronously(RunnableBatchServiceExecutor.java:98) ~[reins-batch-servlet-1.0-20151127.125731-11.jar:na]
                at com.scor.omega2.batch.presentation.servlet.BatchStartServlet.doExecuteBatch(BatchStartServlet.java:161) [reins-batch-servlet-1.0-20151127.125731-11.jar:na]
                at com.scor.omega2.batch.presentation.servlet.BatchStartServlet.doBatch(BatchStartServlet.java:98) [reins-batch-servlet-1.0-20151127.125731-11.jar:na]
                at com.scor.omega2.batch.presentation.servlet.BatchStartServlet.doPost(BatchStartServlet.java:78) [reins-batch-servlet-1.0-20151127.125731-11.jar:na]
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641) [servlet-api.jar:na]
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) [servlet-api.jar:na]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
                at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [na:1.7.0_04]
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [na:1.7.0_04]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_04]
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed.
                at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.TidyXMLStreamReader.close(TidyXMLStreamReader.java:58) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:351) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseUsingMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:218) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:171) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:149) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:120) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:260) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:223) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:171) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:96) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at com.scor.omega2.shared.ws.WorkflowHandlerServiceService.<init>(WorkflowHandlerServiceService.java:53) ~[omega2-shared-services-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
                at com.scor.omega2.core.workflow.WorkflowHandler.startProcess(WorkflowHandler.java:51) ~[omega2-shared-services-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
                at com.scor.omega2.shared.common.service.dao.impl.WorkflowDaoSharedImpl.startStandardWorkflow(WorkflowDaoSharedImpl.java:120) ~[omega2-shared-services-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
                at com.scor.omega2.shared.common.service.impl.WorkflowServiceSharedImpl.startStandardWorkflow(WorkflowServiceSharedImpl.java:62) ~[omega2-shared-services-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor568.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) ~[spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:91) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at com.scor.omega2.batch.utils.AopContextLoader.loadContextAround(AopContextLoader.java:26) ~[AopContextLoader.class:na]
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor209.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at $Proxy746.startStandardWorkflow(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
                at com.scor.omega2.shared.common.service.impl.DairyFrontEndServiceSharedImpl.registerNotification(DairyFrontEndServiceSharedImpl.java:640) ~[omega2-shared-services-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor484.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) ~[spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:91) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at com.scor.omega2.batch.utils.AopContextLoader.loadContextAround(AopContextLoader.java:26) ~[AopContextLoader.class:na]
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor209.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at $Proxy741.registerNotification(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
                at com.scor.omega2.batch.accountingclaim.service.impl.SINJ3010ServiceImpl.execute(SINJ3010ServiceImpl.java:196) ~[omega2-accountingclaim-batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
                at com.scor.omega2.batch.accountingclaim.service.impl.SINJ3010ServiceImpl.execute(SINJ3010ServiceImpl.java:35) ~[omega2-accountingclaim-batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor297.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:91) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at com.scor.omega2.batch.utils.AopContextLoader.loadContextAround(AopContextLoader.java:26) ~[AopContextLoader.class:na]
                at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor209.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
                at $Proxy785.execute(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
                at com.scor.omega2.batch.executor.RunnableBatchServiceExecutor.run(RunnableBatchServiceExecutor.java:133) ~[reins-batch-servlet-1.0-20151127.125731-11.jar:na]
                ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed.
                at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.available(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:458) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at java.net.SocketInputStream.available(SocketInputStream.java:238) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:342) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(ChunkedInputStream.java:543) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(ChunkedInputStream.java:600) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:687) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3035) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser$1.close(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:835) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.TidyXMLStreamReader.close(TidyXMLStreamReader.java:56) ~[na:1.7.0_04]
                ... 105 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Where is  your code?

Comment: I have added the code. Thanks

Comment: What the version of JRE you use?

Comment: We are using JRE 1.7.21

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with JAX-WS version of the JRE referenced by the Eclipse to build the product.
Try to update the version of JRE and JAX-WS.

Comment: There is no other option ? Because we are in PRD, and we get this issue some time may be once in a week or once in 15 days.

Comment: Or do you have referance that this issue is related to JAX-WS or JRE version ?